# AMP cache corrupting the image

Tags: amp-html

I am using amp on my website. When I load the page on mobile it does not load the background image properly. 
Here is URL of the image.

```
https://cdn.ampproject.org/i/s/rentzeal.com/img/index_mobile.jpeg
```

It downloads the image, when I try to open it, it says that the image is corrupted.

I tried update-ping API too

```
https://cdn.ampproject.org/update-ping/i/s/rentzeal.com/img/index_mobile.jpeg
```

But nothing happens. The image is a sprite so lot of component depends on this. I check in developer tool, it says the type of image is webp.

[image]

Also, can you please let me know how to update the cache? I tried the procedure mentioned on the website but I could not get response from the URL

```
https://rentzeal-com.cdn.ampproject.org/update-cache/i/s/rentzeal.com/img/index_mobile.jpeg?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=1503996236123&amp_url_signature=Wxm%2BHAwPLhs4bmVY00XfoJPcbFVyPwpt3ctesK%2FB%2BiQmicKLOyDiewHrK9GFA19lZDRrOH3q7mGB%0D%0AizqBL6C6sS8qSL9EX1HoIvMgN7A05vgc41lrK0E3D2h6yXG4D4rsj7SAu%2FOPyTtuJifHilAN2xHN%0D%0AK%2Fff8HrnhZezeqKI8ryVleI44g0kr3zIppmhFh35pKLlX8%2FywkBhfViJC3ZIcCYdEzQ8NMI7ovP%2F%0D%0ApDt6kswTsNAnw0uWVSY3i9PsFl2ND6Ck2OhxtWXQEnciR0WaaE9cS2XRGMprK6wfM1yBlqXd1Itf%0D%0AQGq6PSpzCEAcrPG8jAjoB%2F28g0q1URJK9SRF%2Fg%3D%3D
```